# Colorize code inside <code></code>

Tags: php, html, bbcode, colorize

I'm looking for a open source PHP script to colorize the code inside

```
<code></code>
```

or

[code][/code] tags.

Thanks

Comment: Which programming language does de `<code></code>` contain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also try a clientside/javascript highlighter: [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)

> - Supports all C-like, Bash-like, and
>     XML-like languages.

*(This is the one used on stackoverflow.com/ and code.google.com/)*

Comment: SWEET. Just what i was looking for.thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want something other than the built-in [syntax highlighter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.highlight-string.php), [GeSHi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/) looks like it might fit your requirements:

> GeSHi started as an idea to create a generic syntax highlighter for the phpBB forum system, but has been generalised to this project. GeSHi aims to be a simple but powerful highlighting class, with the following goals:
>
> - Support for a wide range of popular languages
> - Easy to add a new language for highlighting
> - Highly customisable output formats

Comment: Thanks! But.. Have you tested this script? It looks like I have to preselect the language before the output. I am looking for a more general colorization.

Comment: @cvack - If you go over to http://meta.stackoverflow.com and look at some on the questions on SO's syntax highlighting you'll see that a generic solution isn't really possible. What's a keyword in one application isn't in another etc. so there'll be errors and inaccuracies in the output. By specifying the language you can do a much better (if not perfect) job. Do you have a specific requirement that means you can't preselect the language?

Comment: I'm using MarkItUp jQuery editor and I have no idea how to make a language selecter ;) But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some built in functions for this purpose.  Check if highlight_string or highlight_file will work for you

http://www.php.net/highlight_file

http://www.php.net/highlight_string